# Implementing devise-jwt with Rails 7 web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-7, devise-jwt

I found a lot of tutorials implementing devise and devise-jwt with rails api only application. But I wanted to implement devise-jwt with rails 7 web application. This application has some APIs which needs to be accessed by third party. So I was trying incorporate token based authorization.

Is devise-jwt implementation possible only for API only mode?

I tried to implement it anyway but I don't get any token in the header when signing in.